# R vroom import package - Close connection

Tags: r

I am currently using the R `vroom` package to import data. After importing the data, I wanted to make some manual changes to the underlying csv file. However, I am unable to save any changes because the R session is connected to the file.

Is there a way to disconnect the vroom connection with the file within R session rather than having to close R, make the edit and then import the data.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the option `altrep = FALSE`

The overall syntax would be

`vroom(path, delim = ",", altrep = FALSE)`

Comment: But then the speed of lazy reading is lost.